# Different spacing in \makecvtitle

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, moderncv, cv

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{Firstname}{Lastname}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{myemail@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/mylinkedin}
\homepage{mywebsite.com}           

\pagenumbering{gobble}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

My question is simple: How can I slightly separate (with vertical spacing) `Firstname Lastname` from the phone, email, social, website within `\makecvtitle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way can be as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

% character encoding
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{Firstname}{Lastname}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{myemail@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/mylinkedin}
\homepage{mywebsite.com}           

\pagenumbering{gobble}

% add some vertical space below the name
% original definition is
% \newcommand{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}\vspace{1ex}}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Adjust `1ex` to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendation for the spacing on top of phone, email, social? For example, if I want to bring it *up* when using the `casual` style?